# Why does adding a list to another list, using add range, remove the elements from the first list?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable, addrange

Consider the following example:

```
IEnumerable<Int32> groupsToAdd = new List<Int32>();

List<Int32> groups1 = new List<Int32>() { 1,2,3 };
List<Int32> groups2 = new List<Int32>() { 3,4,5 };

groupsToAdd = groups1.Where(g => false == groups2.Contains(g));

groups2.AddRange(groupsToAdd);

groupsToAdd.Dump();
```

When `groupsToAdd.Dump()` is called the list is now empty. I've looked up the AddRange reference and it doesn't mention that the elements are removed from list but when i test this code (in linqpad) it ends empty. Why is this?

Edit:
To clarify, I mean that the elements are being removed from `groupsToAdd` because before `groups2.AddRange(groupsToAdd)` groupsToAdd is populated with two elements

Comment: There must be some code you're not showing us. The code you have above doesn't alter groups1 at all.

Comment: @itsme86 it doesn't need to

Comment: @itsme86 This is the complete code and this code by itself will 'Dump' a empty list in linqpad and in unit tests.

Comment: If you use `groupsToAdd = groups1.Where(g => false == groups2.Contains(g)).ToList();` instead you materialize the query to a `List<int>`. Then it behaves as expected because there is no deferred execution anymore.

Comment: I don't think you guys are reading the question. The OP says that the code is removing the elements from the first list (i.e. groups1). Not that groupsToAdd is empty.

Comment: @itsme86: _"When groupsToAdd.Dump() is called the list is now empty"_ He thinks that `groupsToAdd` is a list which is incorrect.

Comment: @itsme86 To clarify, I mean that the elements are being removed from groupsToAdd because before "groups2.AddRange(groupsToAdd)" groupsToAdd is populated with two elements

Comment: @TimSchmelter Or he's saying that when `groupsToAdd.Dump()` is called, `groups1` is now empty, which is how I read that.

Comment: @Letseatlunch Oh okay, I was misinterpreting then.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's because of the IEnumerable. When you set groupsToAdd to the result of `groups1.Where(g => false == groups2.Contains(g))` there is deferred execution, which means that the query is not run until AddRange() *and then again* at Dump(). Because the list, groups2, now contains the elements they no longer are a result of the original query.

Answer (score 15):

What's important to remember, when using LINQ, is that it results in a *query*, not the *results of that query*.  `groupsToAdd` is not a list of items, it's just the definition of a query that is able to get some items when it needs to.

`groupsToAdd` doesn't actually iterate the source sequence (which is `groups1`) or perform the predicate checks (which is dependant on the state of `groups2`) until it is iterated.

You iterate `groupsToAdd` twice.  Once with the call to `AddRange`, and again with the call to `Dump`.  The second time you're iterating it `group2` has changed, and thus the results of the query have changed as well.

If you want to avoid this deferred execution then you can materialize the query right away by modifying your code to be something like:

```
groupsToAdd = groups1.Where(g => false == groups2.Contains(g));
    .ToList();
```

This will evaluate the query at that moment in time so that `groupsToAdd` will represent the *results of the query* instead of the *query itself*.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It clearly explains OP's issue.